# ARC is enabled. Why the 'dealloc' method doesn't call?

Tags: objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

ARC is enabled. Why the 'dealloc' method doesn't call? Should I use **@autoreleasepool** here or not? Why?
Thank you.

```
@interface Test : NSObject
@end

@implementation Test

+(id)testFromNothing
{
  id res = [Test alloc];
  return res;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  NSLog(@"deallocated");
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Test* test = [Test testFromNothing];
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should use autorelease pool in `main`. Another problem is that you are not initializing your object in `testFromNothing`.

Reason: You should create autorelease pools wherever a thread is entered (including the main thread). Of course, if that thread just uses C code, then no objc objects will be autoreleased, so it is unnecessary in those scenarios.

Regarding the "Why?" -- ARC also uses the autoreleasing and expects autorelease pools are always in place. Programs need to support autorelease semantics correctly since ARC also assumes it may use autorelease pools, and it is the programmer's responsibility to set up the autorelease pools correctly (in some contexts). ARC is unlike GC, and very similar to MRC regarding the reference count operations and the sequence in which the reference count operations occur. With GC, several collection schemes may be used (e.g. you can see a lot of growth before collection, or collection could happen on secondary threads), but ARC operates similar to well structured retain/release/autorelease operations -- plus a few tricks/extensions.

Comment: `code`id res = [[Test alloc] init]; Without @autoreleasepool 'dealloc' doesn't call yet. Why should I use @autoreleasepool in this case?

Comment: But there are no `autorelease`d objects in this example, so what difference will that make?

Comment: @trojanfoe that assumption may be correct when executed, but it relies on implementation details. regardless, the autorelease pool should exist at thread entries, including the main thread.

Comment: As a general rule I agree, but I cannot see it making any difference in this particular case; there are no `autorelease`d objects created.

Comment: @trojanfoe so it *would* surprise you if adding the autorelease pool resulted in the log message? btw, adding the autorelease pool did exactly that. between the runtime, ARC gen, and naming conventions, there are many surprising operations.

Comment: Yes that would.  Can you explain it please?

Comment: One more question. When **test** will be deleted? __Only__ after we exit @autoreleasepool block?

Comment: @trojanfoe by naming convention and unattributed, `+testFromNothing` returns an autoreleased object. if it is named `+newTestFromNothing` the returned value happens to be deallocated, despite the absence of the autorelease pool. when using the autoreleasing naming convention, the parameter is returned via a different behavior than the non-autoreleased variant. this does not actually require that the object is placed in the pool. google `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue` for elaboration of what's going on under the hood here.

Comment: That is interesting and highlights a gap in my knowledge; I had assumed that if ARC was enabled it would return a `strong` object which would be removed when `main()` returns.  Many thanks; I need to do more study!

Comment: @ssgreg it will be returned to the system when the process exits, for sure. as an implementation detail, the runtime may create an initial autorelease pool for a thread if it is absent -- i've seen no guarantee of that behavior. if you see neither your log message nor a message that says something like "no autorelease pool, just leaking…", then your runtime has created one on your behalf. but you don't actually want that behavior because then it gets drained only when the thread exits (effectively never in the case of the cocoa/cocatouch app when the thread in question is the main thread).

Comment: @ssgreg so in that scenario, your `dealloc` will never be run (although the system will reclaim the memory after the process has exited). and again, you should just assume that you need to create one at thread entry. but even so, those autogenerated autorelease pools for the main thread will likely not grow very large because most of the time, main just goes straight into application main, which creates its own inner autorelease pools.

Comment: @trojanfoe you're welcome -- there are a lot of underlying subtleties/tricks in the runtime. enjoy :)

Comment: How can I release *test* inside of @autoreleaseblock, if I don't need it more?

Comment: @ssgreg `test = 0;` will invalidate the reference you hold -- that simply decrements the reference count. the object's lifetime is not guaranteed to end at that point since other references may exist (including in autorelease pools). so if it is local and you do not share it, creating inner autorelease pools can also help minimize the lifetime in some scenarios. of course, `test = 0;` happens implicitly sometime after it goes out of scope (it's also not guaranteed to be immediately when it goes out of scope).

Comment: @justin Thank you for all your answers.